# Why does Donald die so frequently?

Tags: invincible

Near the end of the second season of the animated series, we see that Donald not only almost died near the end of the first season when Omni-Man confronted him, but in fact has been killed and rebuilt at least dozens of times. By contrast, his boss, as far as we know, has not been killed or rebuilt in a robot body, and uses a teleportation device to avoid threats. We also see little indication that any other agency employees are subject to this procedure—when they are killed, they seem to stay dead.

Why has Donald, in particular, seemingly been killed and put in a new body countless times, as opposed to either being left to die, not risking himself so much in the first place, or using a teleporter like Cecil?

Answer (score 4):

[This Screen Rant page talks about this situation.](https://screenrant.com/invincible-season-2-donald-death-cyborg-twist-explained/) Admittedly, it's basically their opinion as well, but essentially, Donald represents just how dangerous it is to live in a world with superpowers. Even minor "joke" villains kill people, almost incidentally. Donald dies because of this, and because he's willing to continuously put himself on the front line for what he believes. As to why it's just Donald, I think it's essentially because he's such a valuable resource (and one that Cecil values as well). As for why Donald doesn't use a teleporter, there's a one-off line in the comics by Cecil that every use of the teleporter costs $5 million. Cecil doesn't care, by his own admission, but Donald seems like the by-the-book kind of person who would see that as an unacceptable expense (noting, of course, that the second season also revealed that Donald, after his first resurrection, chose to not be aware that he had been killed, as he felt that it might impair his performance in the field).

Comment: I don't know...is rebuilding Donald's body as a state-of-the-art robot every time he nearly dies cheap? And is he—a non-powered, albeit courageous and loyal person—so valuable as to justify whatever that cost might be?

Comment: @Adamant: You have a point. I suspect that the choice is being made by Cecil, who clearly doesn't care nearly as much about the cost (given he proudly points out the expense of the teleport after using it to basically avoid walking), but he's limited by that he would have to make Donald aware of the teleport (there's also a line about how it requires a specific bracelet to work), and Donald may be more cost conscious.